# Customize export filename of Wagtail report?

Tags: wagtail

Is there a way to customize the export filename for reports that are added to the Reports menu in the same way that `export_filename = "xxxxxxx"` works for `ModelAdmin`?  ([ModelAdmin link](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/indexview.html?highlight=export_filename#modeladmin-export-filename))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `get_filename` method on your `PageReportView` subclass. [Wagtail's built-in reports do this as follows](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/5e6a6746869d351eb2c55e092d6e669da1af896f/wagtail/admin/views/reports.py#L68-L81):

```
class LockedPagesView(PageReportView):
    # ...

    def get_filename(self):
        return "locked-pages-report-{}".format(
            datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @gasman.  It would be nice to have something in the docs about that or, better yet, a new feature to override the filename in the same way it is done for `ModelAdmin` - with `export_filename`.